# invoke private var to convenience init (swift)

Tags: swift, class, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

Im trying to create a node class of a ball. the ball supposed to have some physics body properties - because of that i created a function that init the physicsbody properties.  also, I want that the user will set up the ball radius (via circleOfRadius) which I set up via convenience init. because of that I set the radius var as a private. the problem is the I can set the radius to there private var but then the convenience is not executed. 
here is my code:

```
 class BallNode: SKShapeNode {
    var radius:CGFloat = 0
    private var _R:CGFloat?

        override init() {
        super.init()
        self.setPhysics()

    }

var newBallR:CGFloat{
        get {
            return _R!
        }
        set {
            _R = newValue
            self.radius = _R!
            print("bsllRRRR:", self.radius)

        }
    }



    convenience init(radius:CGFloat){
        self.init(circleOfRadius: radius)
        self.radius = radius
        print("successful init circle radius", self.radius)
    }

        func setPhysics() {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(circleOfRadius: self.radius)
        print("physics body is SET with value:", self.radius)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        print("gravity = T")
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        print("res = 0.2")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let positionOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)


        let ball = BallNode(radius:65)
        }
```

I know I can solve that by cancel the private radius var and declare the physics body property inside the convenience init but im not sure if its correct. 
one more thing, when I check the code the _R! getting the 65 value, but as I said the convenience init is not executed. 
can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are not calling the convenience init. Use `BallNode(radius:65.0)`, then it gets called and `myRadius` will be set to 65.0 but whats the use, you aren't calling `setPhysics()` in your convenience init.

Comment: not working, actually my code here isn't correct. it should be as you said. I will fix it.